# Label Outgoing email in Gmail

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, cakephp-2.0, email-headers

I'm working on a PHP application that uses CakePHP and I want to send an email from a GMail inbox that includes a email label.

As an example: I have the label 'work' in my GMail inbox, I need the php application to append the work label to an email message and then send that message.

I am using SMTP via CakePHP's email library to send this email from the gmail inbox. I am not sure if it is possible to append a label using these tools. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Labels are an internal GMail mechanism and as such not part of the email protocol or anything of the like. GMail labels incoming emails based on user-defined filters, e.g. mails coming from a certain address or containing certain words or phrases.

If you want to label certain emails with certain tags, then you need to create the rules in your GMail, and then send out emails following these rules.

For instance, you could create a rule applying the tag 'work' to every email coming from CakePHP's email address with the word [work] in the title, and then send emails like that.

An alternative and somewhat more fancy solution would be to make use of [GMail's plus-aliasing](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en). Assuming your email is *yourname@gmail.com*, all emails going to *yousername+something@gmail.com* will also arrive in your inbox. Therefore, you could send mails to *yourname+work@gmail.com* and create a filter for those in GMail.